# nodeJs spawn process returning <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a>

Tags: python, node.js

I m running simple python script from nodeJs with child-process.
In console its showing <Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 0a> instead of 'hello'

js code

```
const childPython = spawn('python',['./python/attendance.py']);

childPython.stdout.on('data',data=>{
    console.log(data);
})
childPython.stderr.on('data',data=>{
    console.log(data);
})
```

python file

```
print('hello')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to turn the buffer into a string

```py
const childPython = spawn('python',['./python/attendance.py']);

childPython.stdout.on('data',data=>{
    console.log(data.toString());
})
childPython.stderr.on('data',data=>{
    console.log(data.toString());
})
```

[Read More Here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-integrate-a-python-ruby-php-shell-script-with-node-js-using-child-process-spawn-e26ca3268a11/)